# mongoose get data from find method and insert them in other schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to build a web application.

At the website, I need to get instructor data from mongodb with mongoose and some of them will be inserted in other schema(Course).

```
if (!req.body) return console.log("No data sent");
    var newcourse;
    var iname = req.body.iname;
    var results;


/*ilist.find({ name: iname }).toArray((err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    results = result;
});*/
dbs.collection('instructors').find({ name: iname }).toArray((err, result) => {
    results = result;
    //console.log(result);        
});
// console.log(ilist.data);

newcourse = new clist({
    'coursename': req.body.coursename, 'coursenumber': req.body.coursenumber, 'coursecredit': req.body.coursecredit
    , 'courseroom': req.body.room, 'instructors.name': req.body.iname, 'instructors.email': results.email, 'instructors.phone': results.phone, 'instructors.role': req.body.role
});

newcourse.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(400);
        res.send(err);
    }
    else {
        res.status(200);
        console.log('A new course has been registered!');
        res.redirect('/course');
    }
});
```

-----schema-------------------

```
var instructorlist = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    age: { type: Number, required: true },
    gender: { type: String, required: true },
    DOB: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    phone: { type: Number, required: true },
    address: { type: String, required: true },
    dateofstart: { type: Date, required: true},
    courses: {
        coursename: { type: String, required: false },
        coursenumber: { type: Number, requird: false },
        coursecredit: { type: Number, required: false },
        courseroom: { type: String, required: false }
    }
});
var courselist = mongoose.Schema({
    coursename: { type: String, required: true },
    coursenumber: { type: String, required: true },
    coursecredit: { type: Number, required: true },
    courseroom: { type: String, required: false },
    courseregisteddate: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    students: {
        name: { type: String, required: false },
        phone: { type: Number, requird: false },
        email: { type: String, required: false },
        class: { type: String, required: false }
    },
    instructors: {
        name: { type: String, required: false },
        phone: { type: Number, requird: false },
        email: { type: String, required: false },
        role: { type: String, required: false }
    }
});
```

I want to get instuctorlist's email and phone.(others are from req.body) and
put it into newcourse variable for saving in mongodb.
Thank you for reading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructors find function will be called asynchronously so the javascript code will go on before you have the results of that mongoose query.

You need to add the saving of the course inside the callback. Could look like this:

```js
if (!req.body) return console.log("No data sent");

dbs.collection('instructors').find({
  name: req.body.iname
}).toArray((err, instructors) => {
  if (!err) {
    if (!instructors) {
      var newcourse = new clist({
        // new data also from instructors
      });

      newcourse.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
          res.status(400);
          res.send(err);
        }
        else {
          res.status(200);
          res.redirect('/course');
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      res.status(400);
      res.send("Could not find instructor");
    }
  }
  else {
    res.status(400);
    res.send(err);
  }
});
```

But be aware that with this you get all instructors with the given name and you have to select one from that array. If you want to save more courses to a instructor you have to change the schema:
e.g.

```js
var courseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  // Schema variables
  ...

});

var courseModel = mongoose.model("Course", courseSchema);

var instructorlist = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

  ...

  courses: [{
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: "Course"
  }]
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try it and saw the similar case but didn't understand exactly. Thank you again :)

Comment: The ref means that it refers Course. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes ref will save the id of the course in the instructor table in the database. So you do not have to save the same values again. If you want to get the real values you have to use `populate`. Take a look at that functionality too